# пропущено ли "бы"?

Tags: сослагательное, наклонение

*Даже если бы эта хирургическая процедура не смогла устранить боль как таковую, она была способна притупить эмоциональные реакции и помочь Эвите переносить страдания.*

По-моему, необходимо перед "способна" написать "бы". Как это доказать?

Answer (score 4):

Подтипы придаточных условия:

1) Потенциальное условие (без частицы БЫ)

Даже если  эта хирургическая процедура не сможет устранить боль как таковую, она будет способна притупить эмоциональные реакции и помочь Эвите переносить страдания.

2) Ирреальное (нереальное) условие (с частицей БЫ в обеих частях предложения, возможен повтор частицы)

Даже если бы эта хирургическая процедура не смогла (бы) устранить боль как таковую, она была бы способна притупить эмоциональные реакции и помочь Эвите переносить страдания.

Answer (score 3):

Если смысл в том, что "оказалась-таки способна облегчить", то нужно убирать первое "бы" и заменять "если" на "хотя", в противном случае нужно добавить второе "бы" (в указанном Вами месте). Без таких изменений оказываются логически рассогласованными две части предложения: они должны быть либо обе в сослагательном наклонении, либо обе без такового.